# Why is my condition always false?

Tags: shell-script, test

I tried to write a script which creates a user.

First it needs to check if:

1. root is running
2. if user maybe already exists

I Also tried to set the password equal to the username which was typed in.

Overall this works fine if i copy it step by step and execute it step by step. 
But the whole script won't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    read -p "User: " username
    pass=$username

    if [ getent username>/dev/null 2>&1 ]; then
        echo "$username already exists"
        sleep 10
        exit 1
    else    
        useradd -m $username
        echo "$pass" | passwd $username --stdin
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User was created" || echo "Error while creating"
        unset username

    fi
else
    echo "No root"
    sleep 3
    exit 2  
fi
```

Comment: "Won't work" is not a very useful statement. What happens? My guess it that you are explicitly executing it with a shell that doesn't support `-p`.

Comment: Also, you need `if getent passwd "$username" ...` with no `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` command introduces a conditional; it is [synonymous with `test`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28682/test-and-different-binaries-any-difference) except for requiring a closing bracket at the end. Inside the brackets, you need a condition such as `-n "$foo"` to test if a variable is non-empty, `-e foo` to test if a file exists, etc.

`[ getent username>/dev/null 2>&1 ]` is equivalent to `test getent username>/dev/null 2>&1`. The conditional expression is not well-formed, so this produces an error message such as `[: 1: getent: unexpected operator`, which is redirected to `/dev/null` so you don't see it. The conditional command returns 0 if the condition is true, 1 if it's false and 2 if there is an error; here it returns 2, and `if` takes then `then` branch only if the command returns 0, so the `if` statement takes the `else` branch.

You can get an idea of what's going on by activating traces by putting `set -x` as the second line of your script. This will tell you that the `[ getent username>/dev/null 2>&1 ]` command is executed followed by the `useradd -m $username` command, but to see why `[ getent username>/dev/null 2>&1 ]` is failing, you have to remove the redirection.

Since you don't want to use a conditional expression here, but to test if `getent "$username"` succeeds (not `getent username`, by the way), leave off the brackets:

```
if getent "$username" >/dev/null 2>&1; then …
```

Answer (score 3):

The `if` command does not *require* square brackets. The condition part of the `if` statement is actually just a command and if that command exits sucessfully, the "true" part of the `if` statement is executed. The open square bracket is actually a command name (the close square bracket is just an argument passed to the `[` command).

If you want to check that the username exists, do this:

```
if getent passwd $username &>/dev/null; then ...
```

Remove the "sleep 10". If I was using your script that would just irritate me.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used this form which:

- fix the usage error by stating the database to query (`passwd`)
- doesn't require redirecting stdout
- leave stderr alone as there is no point ignoring it

---

```
if [ "$(getent passwd username)" ]
```